# Save value of object in vector and pointer in map. Is this correct?

Tags: c++

I have a question of the validity of pointers of objects in `std::vector`s. I am not sure if the memory in the following example is saved correctly and if I am accessing the pointers in the way I intend to do:

```
// class which should hold the 4 Indices
struct Face
{
    Face(){};
    Face(std::array<int, 4> indices) : Indices(indices) // array is copied and saved in face object
    {}
    std::array<int, 4> Indices{};
}

static void CreateAndStoreFace(const std::array<int, 4>& indices,
                          std::vector<Face>& faces,
                          std::map<int, Face*>& indexToFaces)
{
    Face f(indices); // create a face on the stack, indices are copied
    faces.push_back(f); // pushed into vector, face is copied on "vector-heap"
    for(const auto& index : indices)
    {
        indexToFaces[index] = &faces[faces.size() - 1]; // face pointer is saved in map
    }
}
```

So my question is, is the pointer in the `map` pointing to the correct object? Is the face on the heap and can it be used later from inside the `vector` and the `map`?

I think you understand what I'm trying to do, do you see an easier (or correct) implementation of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how do you use your `CreateAndStoreFace` function. If the lifetime of `faces` is longer than `indexToFaces`, and the `faces` vector does not invalidate its references (e.g. after another `push_back`), then the pointer in your map always points to the correct block of memory.

```
std::vector<Face> faces;
std::map<int, Face*> indexToFaces;
CreateAndStoreFace(indices, faces, indexToFaces);
// indexToFaces[someIdx] returns a pointer pointing to some Face
```

```
std::map<int, Face*> indexToFaces;
{
  std::vector<Face> faces;
  CreateAndStoreFace(indices, faces, indexToFaces);
}
// indexToFaces[someIdx] using this pointer is undefined behavior
```

```
std::vector<Face> faces;
std::map<int, Face*> indexToFaces;
CreateAndStoreFace(indices, faces, indexToFaces);
faces.push_back(anotherFace);
// indexToFaces[someIdx] using this pointer is undefined behavior - vector might invalidate the references
```

BTW, instead of `faces[faces.size() - 1]` you can just `faces.back()`

Comment: I accept this answer because it considers lifetime of map and vector. The vector and map are stored in the same object and have therefor the same lifetime. I only need a fast access to find the face behind the index

Answer (score 1):

> is the pointer in the map pointing to the correct object?

Yes, it is.

> Is the face on the heap and can it be used later from inside the vector and the map?

No, you are taking a pointer to a local variable, so when you return from the function, the pointer to it is dangling.

You can allocate a `Face` on the heap if you want:

```
auto fp = new Face{indices};
faces.push_back(*fp);
```

Now the pointers inside the `map` and `vector` are valid when you return from the function. However, if you modify the `vector` with something like `push_back` then the pointers in the `map` are no longer guaranteed to point to valid objects.

Also, don't forget to delete this memory at some point.

Comment: Note that in the example `Face f` is pushed into a vector by copy. Then `&faces[faces.size() - 1];` points to the address of the object inside the vector, not of the local variable. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @pptaszni Yes, that's correct. But the `map` holds a pointer to the `Face` inside the `vector` so that's fine.